# Join two pyspark dataframes to update values when match on certain columns

Tags: pyspark

I have two dataframes, data_new and data_old, I want to join those two in that way that:

- if column name and index of data_new appear in df_old but value in name_2 and index_2 and string differ then I want to use the values from data_new in that columns
- if there are are rows that are in data_new but not in data_old (with respect to name and index), I want to keep the rows
- if there are rows in data_old that are not in data_new(with respect to name and index) I want to keep the whole row as well
  so given this example dataframes:

```
 columns = ["name","index","name_2","index_2","string"]
 data_new = [(1,0,3,0,"C"),
                   (1,1,3,1,"C"),
                   (1,2,3,2,"C"),
                  (1,3,3,3,"C"),
                  (3,0,3,4,"C"),
                  (3,1,3,5,"C")]
  data_old = [(1,0,1,0,"A"),
                   (1,1,1,1,"A"),
                   (1,2,1,2,"A"),
                  (1,3,1,3,"A"),
                   (2,0,2,0,"B"),
                   (2,1,2,1,"B"),
                  (2,2,2,2,"B"),
                  (2,3,2,3,"B")]
```

I would like to get

```
|name|index|name_2|index_2|string|
|----|-----|------|-------|------|
|1   | 0   |3     |0      |C     |
|1   |1    |3     |1      |C     |
|1   |2    |3     |2      |C     |
|1   |3    |3     |3      |C     |
|3   |0    |3     |4      |C     |
|3   |1    |3     |5      |C     |
|2   |0    |2     |0      |B     |
|2   |1    |2     |1      |B     |
|2   |2    |2     |2      |B     |
|2   |3    |2     |3      |B     |
```

Doing a full join gives me two columns for name_2 and index_2 and string with different values in it.
Left join kills the data which is only present in the old dataframe and right join does not update the values in the way I want them to. I could try to combine mutliple joins but maybe there is a better way to do this?

In addition to that: Another idea would be to not use a join at all but to save all name/index from dataframe_new to a list, use this list to filter all those out in dataframe_old and then union data_new to data_old.
Using lists and searching for values in it doesn't seem so spark-like to me but does someone of you know if a join or this list thing would be more efficient? We are talking about big dataframes here (data_old: ~10 Billion rows, data_new: ~10 Million)

Sorry for such a long question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove all data from old which is also in new based on `name` and `index`, then union the result with the new data. This can be done by an [anti join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join) and a [union](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.union.html).

```
df_new = spark.createDataFrame(data_new, columns)
df_old = spark.createDataFrame(data_old, columns)

df = (df_old
    .join(df_new, on=['name', 'index'], how='anti')
    .union(df_new)
)

df.show()

+----+-----+------+-------+------+                                              
|name|index|name_2|index_2|string|
+----+-----+------+-------+------+
|   2|    3|     2|      3|     B|
|   2|    2|     2|      2|     B|
|   2|    0|     2|      0|     B|
|   2|    1|     2|      1|     B|
|   1|    0|     3|      0|     C|
|   1|    1|     3|      1|     C|
|   1|    2|     3|      2|     C|
|   1|    3|     3|      3|     C|
|   3|    0|     3|      4|     C|
|   3|    1|     3|      5|     C|
+----+-----+------+-------+------+
```

As you've described the requirements you're not really interested in 'updating' a row, you simply want to keep only the newest row per 'name' and 'index'.