# Replace values of one pyspark dataframe with another

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe `df2` :-

| ID | Total_Count | Final_A | Final_B | Final_C | Final_D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 80 | 36 | 30 | 8 | 6 |
| 4 | 80 | 36 | 30 | 8 | 6 |
| 13 | 65 | 30 | 24 | 6 | 5 |
| 12 | 56 | 26 | 21 | 5 | 4 |
| 2 | 65 | 30 | 24 | 6 | 5 |
| 1 | 56 | 26 | 21 | 5 | 4 |

I have another dataframe `df1` :-

| ID | Total_Count | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 80 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| 11 | 80 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 13 | 65 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 12 | 56 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 65 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 56 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 10 | 34 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 4 |

I want to replace values of `df1` by `df2` for respective `ID`(primary key).
Expected `df1` :-

| ID | Total_Count | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 80 | 36 | 30 | 8 | 6 |
| 4 | 80 | 36 | 30 | 8 | 6 |
| 13 | 65 | 30 | 24 | 6 | 5 |
| 12 | 56 | 26 | 21 | 5 | 4 |
| 2 | 65 | 30 | 24 | 6 | 5 |
| 1 | 56 | 26 | 21 | 5 | 4 |
| 10 | 34 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 4 |

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69526078/join-two-pyspark-dataframes-to-update-values-when-match-on-certain-columns/69529781#69529781

Comment: how to deal with diff column names?

Answer (score 0):

```
df2=spark.read.option("header","True").option("inferSchema","True").csv("df1.csv")
df1=spark.read.option("header","True").option("inferSchema","True").csv("df2.csv")

df2 = df2.withColumnRenamed("ID",'df2_ID').withColumnRenamed("Total_Count",'df2_Total_Count')

final_df = df1.join(df2,(df1.ID ==  df2.df2_ID) & (df1.Total_Count ==  df2.df2_Total_Count),"left")

from pyspark.sql.functions import when
for i in ('A','B','C','D'):
  final_df = final_df.withColumn(i, when(final_df[i] == 0, final_df["Final_{}".format(i)]).otherwise(final_df[i]))

cols = df2.columns
final_df = final_df.drop(*cols)
```

Comment: what condition is this?  `final_df = final_df.withColumn(i, when(final_df[i] == 0, final_df["Final_{}".format(i)]).otherwise(final_df[i]))`

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df1.join(df2.select('Final_A', 'Final_B', 'Final_C', 'Final_D'), 'ID'], 'left')
df =df.withColumn('A', coalesce(df['Final_A'],df['A'])).\
       withColumn('B', coalesce(df['Final_B'],df['B'])).\
       withColumn('C', coalesce(df['Final_C'],df['C'])).\
       withColumn('D', coalesce(df['Final_D'],df['D']))

df1 = df.select('ID', 'Total_Count','A', 'B', 'C', 'D')

df1.show()
```

Comment: this is an inner join . from the example above you can see that not all rows are common right. I need to retain rows of `df1` too